# GitHub account setup in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, git, github

How do i set up my GitHub account in my Ubuntu machine?

Via Command Line, I have configured the email & username variables, when doing the `git push` for the first time & I entered my account credentials when prompted. But it throws the error `remote: Invalid username or password.`

I have enabled  **Two-factor authentication (2FA)** in my account & when i tried with similar approach via **Git CMD** in Windows, an UI window popped up to enter & verify the 2FA .

How it should be achieved in Ubuntu ?

Ubuntu OS version: 20.04
GitHub Version: 2.25.1

Comment: Maybe you need to use GitHub API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the search of answers, found that - As it directly doesn't support the 2FA, need to configure anyone of the below authentication approach to connect to/get/push code from/to private repositories

- Authenticate using [ssh keys](https://github.com/settings/keys) - the related GitHub documentation could found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
- Authenticate using [personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) - the related GitHub documentation could found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)